# Howto compile sqlite3 in my C++ app?

Tags: c++, sqlite

SOLUTION: I just added `-lpthread -ldl` flags to my makefile and it works! Have no idea why, but I'm lucky enough to avoid compiling of sqlite3 by hand as I was trying.. Hmm, anyway some answers where pretty good. Thanks guys, will go and drink some tea for you.

Three months ago I was able to find how to do that but now it is not working. I have a huge C++ app, where I need to embed the sqlite3 code, but I can't compile it. I use something like this:

```
gcc sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl -o ./sqlite3.o
```

But it does not work; I have tried a lot of variations. I have a makefile, where I added sqlite3.h and sqlite3.c files. When I do `make && make install` in my app's particular folder, it shows errors:

```
.libs/sqlite3.o: In function `pthreadMutexTry':
/home/.../client/sqlite3.c:17769: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
.libs/sqlite3.o: In function `pthreadMutexAlloc':
/home/.../client/sqlite3.c:17637: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/home/.../client/sqlite3.c:17638: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/home/.../client/sqlite3.c:17640: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
```

This means that I need to add the `-lpthread` flag, when trying to compile sqlite3 separately from the app. Well, I am stuck.

Comment: Maybe you should post your Makefile...

Comment: The SQLite mailing list would almost certainly be a more appropriate place for this. This is not a question about a programming language, but a request for personal assistance with a build problem.

Comment: Okay, sorry, will go to their mailing list. However I don't want to sign for the list in order to solve this problem as well. Thus I will kill myself.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Why should that matter?  Is this not a practical, answerable question that is unique to the programming profession?  Does it not cover tools commonly used by programmers?

Comment: @SophieSperner: Don't do that!!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: My SO "political" standpoint is further to the right than yours. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `-c` flag to produce an object file and not link. And skip the libraries — you pass them when linking the entire application.

```
gcc -c -o sqlite3.o sqlite3.c
```

Comment: Thank you, it compiled and now I have these files in my app subfolder: sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, sqlite3.lo, sqlite3.o

But I still have problems with pthread described in my question.

Answer (score 4):

The order of the libraries on the command line when linking matters. Put the libraries (`-lpthread -ldl`) last.

Comment: Well, maybe sometimes it matters, but in my case it did not.